# Prime number in Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, primes

```
#Write your code below this line 
def prime_checker(number):
    for num in range (2, number):
        if num % number == 0:
            print("It is not a prime number")
        else:
            print("It is a prime number")


#Write your code above this line 
    
#Do NOT change any of the code below
n = int(input("Check this number: "))
prime_checker(number=n)
```

How can I print a text that number is prime or not only once?

Comment: A hint: if something is *inside a loop body*, then it will happen *on every iteration*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few mistakes in your code. I have modified them.

```
def prime_checker(number):
    for num in range(2, number):
        if number % num == 0:
            print('Not prime')
            return
    print('Prime number')
# Write your code above this line 

# Do NOT change any of the code below
n = int(input("Check this number: "))
prime_checker(number=n)
```

For loop is to check if any of the number starting from 2 is a factor of number or not.

Comment: Thank you. Working. But "how to do to have only one text it is prime number"? http://snap.ashampoo.com/k2di9sBj97NARUK2CrJhwWClMjLDbQ5LMATmSvvRTeSgz8c4PLehdGsqP9Trqr66

Comment: Thank you. My code prints only one time. I didn't used else condition.

Comment: I see. 

Thank you.

I was checking the "return" function.
Without it program print two statement: it is prime and not prime. 

So if we don't add a "return" to a program, the program will check the number and print text, and later go to the next point it means print text: "It is a prime number." But function "return" will stop the program when the condition is being true?

Comment: Your code is a lot easier and more logical for me than my teacher:
```
def prime_checker(number):
    is_prime = True
    for i in range(2, number):
        if number % i == 0:
            is_prime = False
    if is_prime:
        print ("It is a prime number")
    else:
        print('It is not a prime number')
```

Is in this code program check first "for i", later first "if", and later second "if"?

Answer (score 2):

#### Fix

`number % num == 0` and not `num % number == 0`

A number isn't prime the moment you find a number that doesn't divide it, but only when you have tested all and none divides it

Use `for/else` construction, it goes into `else` if no `break` has been used

```
def prime_checker(number):
    for num in range(2, number):
        if number % num == 0:
            print("It is not a prime number")
            break
    else:
        print("It is a prime number")
```

---

Note that this only fixes your way to do, but that isn't the optimal way to check if a numbre is a prime one, at least, ending range at square root of number, and directly verifying division by small numbers like 2,3,5,7

Comment: Thank you. But looks like this code is wrong. It shows us that 4 is a prime number when it is not. http://snap.ashampoo.com/8M5wAoLnfEQ6N4S9XmmWfKzVZfJLhEbFr74sMIasNrP3Nd1gPH7USxLn6vzE11kM

Comment: @KamilKuczyńskizNaukopedia that is NOT the code I wrote. the `else` comes with the `for` not with the `if`, so it should have the indentation of the `for`

Comment: Yes. Thanks. If the else not come with the for, why program print many times text: "It is a prime number"?

Comment: @KamilKuczyńskizNaukopedia because I just spot a big mistake : `number % num == 0` and not `num % number == 0`

Answer (score 0):

First, a slightly more efficient prime check by

- going until the sqrt of the number only
- going in steps of 2

```
import math


def is_prime(n: int) -> bool:
    if n in (2, 3, 5):
        return True
    if n < 2 or n % 2 == 0:
        return False
    for i in range(3, math.ceil(math.sqrt(n)), 2):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Now you can wrap that function in yours

```
def prime_checker(n: int):
    msg = "%d is prime" if is_prime(n) else "%d is not prime"
    print(msg % n)


prime_checker(11)
# 11 is prime
```

Comment: THank you, In this task we can't use math.sqrt(n)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's good to check a number is prime or not

```
def is_prime(n):
    st = "prime" #  being prime status

    for i in range(2,n):
        if n % i == 0: # if number is prime
            st = "not prime"
            break;


    return st 



n = int(input("enter n:  "))
print (is_prime(n))
```

You only need to change the end of your code
your function is true except for these lines:

```
if num % number == 0:
    print("It is not a prime number")
else:
    print("It is a prime number")
```

you should change these to:

```
st = "Prime"
if number % num == 0:
    st = "not prime"
    return st
```